# Cannot install meetme on any version

Tags: asterisk

My app was configured to use MeetMe. After upgradeing my server I noticed MeetMe is no longer an option so I tried to migrate to ConfBridge (the replacement), however everything is broken. How can I force install MeetMe? When I run `Make MenuSelect` it does not let me select MeetMe, just shows  3 x's, and that it is replaced by ConfBridge. I tried Asterisk version 16, 15, 14, 12 and all do not allow me to install MeetMe. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

MeetMe app is based on dahdi-linux package

So it will not give you option until you install pre-request. It just can't work without DAHDI.